# Alternative for Math.log2

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, math

So I have this script that use Javascript's `Math.log2()` function. Tested it in IE 9 today and found out that IE does not support log2. It only supports log.

Does anyone know of a way that I can get the same result as log base 2? An example of my code is below:

```
var number = 16,
    exponent = Math.log2(number);

//Will return 4
return exponent;
```

Comment: the [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2#Polyfill) is `Math.log(x) * Math.LOG2E`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Expression `Math.log(number) / Math.log(2)` is equivalent to `Math.log2(number)`

http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm

Answer (score 13):

You can create a `Math.log2` function if it doesn't exist:

```
Math.log2 = Math.log2 || function(x){return Math.log(x)*Math.LOG2E;};
```